# React Handling component onClick (one opens, but another closes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm having issues with finding a solution or correct direction for my problem. At the moment once you click on -> **className="List-section"**, it will show the information in -> **className="Paragraph-container"**, but there are 4 sections of it and I want to make that if one is open, another closes. Because now I can open all off then, but it has to be opened one at a time only.
If it helps, here's the link to the prototype:
https://www.figma.com/proto/ooya7hVTx4BvdwQQFPXZcj/CCT-Lab-task?node-id=5%3A711&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=5%3A509

Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
function ListItem({ listNumber, listData }) {
  const [isShownOne, setIsShownOne] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="List">
      <div className="List-section" onClick={() => setIsShownOne(!isShownOne)}
      >
        <div className="Section-item">{listNumber}</div>
        <p className="Section-title">{listData.title}</p>
      </div>
      {isShownOne && (
        <div className="List-paragraph">
          {listData.items.map((paragraphItem, index) => (
            <div className="Paragraph-container" key={index}>
              <CheckedIcon  />
              <p className="Paragraph-item">{paragraphItem}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the structure that you have here is not optimal for this behavior that you're looking for.

I would suggest doing something like:

```html
function ListItem({ listNumber, listData }) {
  const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(0);
  
  const totalSections = listData.items.length;
  
  const handleOpenSection = () => {
     const nextSection = currentSection === totalSections ? 0 : currentSection + 1;
     setCurrentSection(nextSection);
  }

  return (
    <div className="List">
      <div className="List-section" onClick={handleOpenSection}
      >
        <div className="Section-item">{listNumber}</div>
        <p className="Section-title">{listData.title}</p>
      </div>
        <div className="List-paragraph">
          {listData.items.map((paragraphItem, index) => (
            {currentSection === index && <div className="Paragraph-container" key={index}>
              <CheckedIcon  />
              <p className="Paragraph-item">{paragraphItem}</p>
            </div>
            }
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you're handling 4 sections, it would be impossible to implement this behavior using a boolean, so this suggestion uses the position of each section in the `items` array to see which one is open at the time.

The `handleOpenSection` function is just a suggestion that seemed fit since you wouldn't want to have a `currentSection` greater than the total sections that you have. Also this code would show the first section in the first render, which is something you might not want to happen!

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the tip! I suppose the logic is correct but I was not able to make it work. The problem is that `listData.items.length` shows the length of items in a paragraph, but not the length of sections. But `listNumber` shows, index of the section, which is `1, 2, 3 and 4`. I will add the rest of the code below, to make more sense of what I'm talking about.

Comment: You're welcome! If I understood correctly, you should be fine just by replacing the `totalSections` with this `listNumber`. The code snippet might be broken also as I coded it without running a real app, but I think that the logic is valid :]

Answer (score 0):

This is where I'm getting data from and passing logic to the component.

```
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      title: "Build test task",
      items: [
        "Create repositor",
        "Implement designs",
        "Implement functionality",
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "Submit your test task",
      items: [
        "Open email client",
        "Sent link information to careers@cornercasetech.com",
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "Participate in tech interview",
      items: ["Talk with HR", "Talk with Tech team"],
    },
    {
      title: "Reciece anster",
      items: ["Receive answers", "Start your IT career"],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>CCT Lab Process</h1>
      </header>
      <div className="App-content">
      {data.map((dataObject, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index} listData={dataObject} listNumber={index + 1} />
      ))}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

And here's where I suppose to be handling the logic for the sections, that if you open one, the previously opened closes and so on.

```
function ListItem({ listNumber, listData }) {
  const [isShownOne, setIsShownOne] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="List">
      <div className="List-section" onClick={() => setIsShownOne(!isShownOne)}
      >
        <div className="Section-item">{listNumber}</div>
        <p className="Section-title">{listData.title}</p>
      </div>
      {isShownOne && (
        <div className="List-paragraph">
          {listData.items.map((paragraphItem, index) => (
            <div className="Paragraph-container" key={index}>
              <CheckedIcon  />
              <p className="Paragraph-item">{paragraphItem}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```